# What happened with the Firefox Developer Edition (Aurora) PPA?

Tags: firefox, ppa

As you can see [from the PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-mozilla-daily/+archive/ubuntu/firefox-aurora), the latest build is from the 17th of October and we're stuck at 51.0a2.

Does anybody have an idea about why the PPA is stale? It was pretty active; also from checking the maintainer's tweets and site I can find no info about it.

Comment: If you're really keen, try https://download.mozilla.org/?product=firefox-aurora-latest-ssl&os=linux64&lang=en-US. Keeping PPAs updated may be depend on volunteers and whether they have time to spare.

Comment: Yep - I'm aware of that approach and I'm also very grateful to the maintainers for their effort - was just wondering about what happened it with it.

Comment: I think that you're looking for this:  https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-mozilla-daily/+archive/ubuntu/ppa